# What is the advantage of sharing sockets between applications?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, optimization

Looking at Circus, a Python app for managing sockets and processes, I'm left wondering what the technical advantage is with sharing/reusing sockets between applications instead of allowing each application their own private socket. Can someone explain this?

Circus's docs can be found here: http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/sockets/#sockets

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "sharing sockets".  If you mean multiple processes sharing a file descriptor for a listening socket and calling `accept()` on it independently, that's really the only way to make that architecture work.

Answer (score 1):

If each child process listens on its own socket, then a parent process will have to handle all connections before distributing them between child process. This is not scalable, since the parent process have too much work.

When multiple child processes share a socket with the parent process ( this is done by forking child processes from the parent process), each child process can accept connection independently, the distribution is handled by the OS kernel, which does it very efficiently.